# al ejecutar mi formulario y darle click en enviar, abre de nuevo el formulario en el que estaba trabajando

Tags: php, mysql

'este es mi código, y no se si el problema esta en mi query o en mis condicionales, relleno mi formulario de empleados y tiene que llevarme a la pagina de listado de empleados pero solo me lleva nuevamente al mismo formulario de carga, como si fuese que cargue un dato en blanco

```
if(!empty($_POST['empleado_nombre'])&& !empty($_POST['empleado_edad']))
{
    $conexionbd = conectar_bd();
    $query = "INSERT INTO empleado (nombre,edad) VALUES
            **('".$_POST['empleado_nombre']."','".$_POST['empleado_edad']."')";**
    $exito= mysqli_query($query,$conexionbd);
    if($exito)
    {
            header('Location: listaempleados.php');
    }
    else
    {
            header('Location: nuevoempleado.php');
    }
}
else
{
    header('Location: nuevoempleado.php');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambia tus parámetros
 $exito= mysqli_query($query,$conexionbd);

de esta manera

$exito= mysqli_query($conexionbd, $query);